# Windows 10 stuck long on Welcome screen after boot

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-10

I have clean installed Windows 10 Pro, and Samsung 850 EVO SSD. On windows 8 there were some times when even the os load screen didn't shown up. On windows 10 i have nearly 10-15 sec of welcome screen. 
Win 8.1 took <20 sec from desktop to desktop, but now the 10 is easily go over 1 minute.

I've tried installing Samsung Magican and optimize the PC- no effect

tried reinstalling - no effect

tried to set automatic Net. TCP port sharing (read somewhere it can cause it)- no effect

tried disabling all startup programs- no effect.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: use the Win10 SDK/WPT (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run this command to do a boot trace: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE and share the compressed file

Comment: @magicandre1981 edited my question with boot trace

Comment: @Shapperd Is Fast Boot option enabled in BIOS ?

Comment: Yes it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

From the trace I see no long delay.

[image]

Your Windows boots in 9 seconds to the desktop and your Windows is fully booted in 15.5 seconds.

The welcome screen is part of the WinLogonInit phase and this only takes 2.9 seconds. This is fine so far.

Comment: Yeah because it was a restart, but when it booted from OFF state it's long.

Comment: does this only happen when the system was off?

Comment: Yes, only when it boot from off.

Comment: when you run the command and windows shuts down, can you please turn the PC off completely. Wait some time and turn it on. Do you also see the delay? If yes, share the trace file.

Comment: I can't really reproduce it.. every day when i turn it IN when i wake up its more than 1 minute or when i came back from work/school it's also 1+ minute.. now it's under 30 sec

Comment: run the command and turn your PC off. leave it off for several hours and when you turn it on, share the newly generated file

Comment: have you captured a new trace when having the device off for a longer time?

Comment: No i couldn't because it restarts when i press enter. But i reinstalled, my pc (fully formatted SSD) with 8.1 and the problem is still there, so it wasn't the win10 problem :(

Comment: but you can sop the restart by holding the power button for several seconds when you see the BIOS output again. Capture a new trace, but this time with the 8.1 version of the WPT. The win10 tools have bug under 8.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

Comment: I know seah it shuts downs intantly, bt same as restart. And even after longer power off.... So i don't really know what is happening...

Comment: and does the delay still only happen on the first boot?

Comment: Yes, it's only happen on first boot.

Comment: I have no idea how to trace this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my PC usually does weird things, so i'm not suprised :,D

Answer (score 0):

I hope i could help, try not lose internet connection during Login, Logout, Restart and Shutdown, check windows update and install updates until no more updates, if possible try to use wired internet connection (LAN/Ethernet), also turn off sync setting at accounts setting, at my Windows 10 PC it solved many error and problem including Cortana activation, ESENT error, windows update service could not be established  and Metadata staging failure when Login and Logout or Restart.